# Find the combining function height using foldTree

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function height that takes two functions `height_c` and `height_b`, where `height_b` is the base case that calculates the height of a tree.

Here's what I have to write,

```
height :: Tree a -> Int
height = foldTree height_c height_b

height_c :: a -> Int -> Int -> Int
height_c = undefined

height_b :: Int
height_b = undefined
```

Also useful are the definitions of `foldTree` and `Tree`,

```
data Tree a
= Tip
| Bin a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
deriving (Show)

foldTree
:: (a -> b -> b -> b)   -- combining function
-> b                    -- base case
-> Tree a               -- input tree
-> b                    -- answer
foldTree c b (Bin x l r) = c x (foldTree c b l) (foldTree c b r)
foldTree c b Tip         = b
```

I was thinking something like

```
height_b Tip = 0
```

for the base case, simple enough.

Now in terms of `height_c` I'm a little lost on where to begin. I'm not exactly sure how `foldTree` even works so that's probably the part that is messing me up the most.

Comment: `height_c` takes the value of the node, the height of the left subtree, the height of the right subtree, and should return the height of the entire tree...

Answer (score 1):

> Now in terms of `height_c` I'm a little lost on where to begin. I'm not exactly sure how `foldTree` even works so that's probably the part that is messing me up the most. Any helpful advice or explanations?

`height_c` takes the value of the node, the height of the left subtree, the height of the right subtree, and should return the height of the entire tree. You thus implement this with:

```
height_c :: a -> Int -> Int -> Int
height_c x hl hr = …
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Still don't really understand foldTree but I should be able to reverse engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with a push from Willem. Thank you!

```
height :: Tree a -> Int
height = foldTree height_c height_b

height_c :: a -> Int -> Int -> Int
height_c a hl hr = 1 + max hl hr

height_b :: Int
height_b = 0
```